# Two way binding not working in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a WPF application with several dialogs with lots of controls. I have a dropdown list that is not binding from the C# to the XAML. The other way around works fine.

Here is the C#:

```
public class AdditionalCostView : ViewBase, IEquatable<AdditionalCostView>
{
    // ..
    public OfficeReferenceDataView Category
    {
        get { return _category; }
        set
        {
            this._category = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Category");
        }
    }
    // ..
}
```

and here is the corresponding XAML:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Validation.Error="Validation_Error"
            DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="ID"
            ItemsSource="{Binding AllCategories}">
    <ComboBox.SelectedItem>
        <Binding Path="Category" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.NotifyOnValidationError>
                <sys:Boolean>true</sys:Boolean>
            </Binding.NotifyOnValidationError>
            <Binding.NotifyOnSourceUpdated>
                <sys:Boolean>true</sys:Boolean>
            </Binding.NotifyOnSourceUpdated>
            <Binding.NotifyOnTargetUpdated>
                <sys:Boolean>true</sys:Boolean>
            </Binding.NotifyOnTargetUpdated>
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <validators:MandatoryValueValidationRule IsRequired="True"  Message="Please select a category."></validators:MandatoryValueValidationRule>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </ComboBox.SelectedItem>
</ComboBox>
```

The AllCategories binding is working fine, but the SelectedItem binding is not. ViewBase implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

When I change the value of Category in my view in C#, nothing happens to the dropdown.

Where am I going wrong?

**UPDATE**

As per comment request, here is the code where I set my value:

```
private void ctlBooking_PricesAndFees_AdditionalCostEditing(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        AdditionalCostEventArgs args = e as AdditionalCostEventArgs;
        AdditionalCostView costToEdit = args.AdditionalCost;
        AdditionalCostView tempCost = args.AdditionalCost.Clone() as AdditionalCostView;
        // ..
    }
    // ..
}
```

I know what you're thinking, because I thought the same thing. The Clone() is not copying the values or raising the events, but it is. I wrote it longhand after the clone to explicitly set those values but that still didn't work.

M

Comment: You may have a conflict between "SelectedValuePath" and "SelectedItem". Have you tried removing "SelectedValuePath"?

Comment: On the other side, are you *actually* changing to an item in the list? Or do the properties just match?

Comment: Do you see any binding errors in output window? Do you set the `Category` form objects in the `AllCategories` list?

Comment: If I remove those to attributes, I get default text in my dropdowns. I think they perform an en entirely different function don't they?

Comment: BradleyDotNET I'm not sure what you mean "the Category form objects in the AllCategories list?"

Comment: Post the code for "... change the value of Category in my view in C#"

Comment: Hamlet Hakobyan - no errors in the output window, and I set the property by using the setter in the first block of code above.

Comment: did you override HashCode method, and how it look like.

Comment: Is the `Category` property *actually* being set to an time in the `AllCategories` collection? you may just have an equality check issue.

Comment: Your code doesn't match:  Category != tempCost. Or whatever else you're rying to say. Write a small but complete example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this XAML (don't forget to declare your *data*):

```
<UserControl.DataContext> <!--<Window.DataContext>-->
    <data:AdditionalCostView />
</UserControl.DataContext> <!--</Window.DataContext>-->    

<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
        DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="ID"
        ItemsSource="{Binding AllCategories, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValue="{Binding Category.ID, Mode=TwoWay" />
```

Apply your ValidationRules in your model not in your UI. Search about DataAnnotations :P

Comment: Where do I put the <UserControl.DataContext />? I get errors wherever I put it.

Comment: @serlingpa if you are using UserControl you put UserControl, if you use Window put Window there. :)